# Proguard: Keep all classes that have annotation

Tags: android, proguard

I want to keep the class name and class fields names of all classes that have my custom Annotation:

```
@Retention(CLASS)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
public @interface DoNotObfuscate {
}
```

I tried this:

```
-keep @com.mypackage.DoNotObfuscate public class *
```

but that did not work.

Comment: Try `@Keep` - an integrated annotation I think doesn't obfuscate the class

Comment: @tynn it was obfuscated

Comment: @LunarWatcher that didn't work either

Comment: It is not well-defined. You should add an example and the current result.

Answer (score 1):

In order to keep class fields you should add "{*;}" at the end:

```
-keep @com.mypackage.DoNotObfuscate public class * {*;}
```